# Can I remove the loading wheel from a flutter SplashScreen

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I am using the standard SplashScreen object on my application, it has a field to change to the color of the loading wheel, but none to remove the loader. I would like the image centered with nothing underneath it. Is it possible to remove the loading wheel?

```
 return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 2,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new RootPage(auth: widget.auth),
      image: new Image.asset('assets/icon.png'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      photoSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2 - 100,),
    )
```

It's an actual object from the flutter library. It has a loading circle with it when you run the Splash

Comment: what loading wheel? CircularProgressIndicator()? can you show some code

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Comment: better use a custom splash screen with timer(), making a widget invisible is not a good practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using SplashScreen Package, I think there is no value to remove the indicator, but you could try make its color transparent

```
return SplashScreen(
  seconds: 2,
  navigateAfterSeconds: new RootPage(auth: widget.auth),
  image: Image.asset('assets/icon.png'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  photoSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2 - 100,),
  loaderColor: Colors.transparent //this will make it invisible
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
    useLoader:false;
```